# kPasteboardTypeFileURLPromise source example

Tags: macos, cocoa, drag-and-drop, nspasteboard

Which application of Apple does support dragging of kPasteboardTypeFileURLPromise items?

I am implementation a kPasteboardTypeFileURLPromise dragging destination and I would like to test it against a dragging source that can be trusted.

(Finder is an example for dragging destination, but I'm looking for a dragging source)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acorn's layer list provide kPasteboardTypeFileURLPromise.  You can drag the image thumbnail out of it, and it'll do the right thing.